# Sorting Laravel collection by 2 parameters

Tags: php, sorting, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

It's fun with sorting today! Sigh. I have a big collection of eloquent models that need to be grouped together in the array by one parameter, and ordered in those 'clumps' based on another parameter. This might be hard to explain :(

$master is a collection of Eloquent results, I'm not sure how to write them out here, looping over this I can access all the models functions / relationships

```
$master = [];
```

These have 2 properties that need to be the basis for a sort, example of the properties below

```
//Object 1
$master->carry = 0;
$master->section = 'red';

//Object 2
$master->carry = 1;
$master->section = 'blue';

//Object 3
$master->carry = 0;
$master->section = 'blue';
```

I want to sort a massive collection of these so that each $master->section is in one 'clump' in the array and inside that 'clump' the $master->carry=0 products are listed last.

```
From the example above I'd expect Object1, Object3, Object2
```

I've tried a few different $master->sort() and $master->sortBy() things, but each new sort throws off the old sort :(

I've got the code below currently, which groups up all the colors, but it doesn't order them based on $master->carry yet

```
$order = array('red', 'blue', 'green');

    $master = $master->sort(function ($a, $b) use ($order) {
        $pos_a = array_search($a->sectionheader, $order);
        $pos_b = array_search($b->sectionheader, $order);
        return $pos_a - $pos_b;
    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I understood, you want to sort your collection the following way:

- sort by section in the order stored in **$order** array
- within section move the elements with **carry = 0** to the end

You need to pass a function that would implement such logic to **$master** collection. This function should take 2 arguments (2 elements of collection), compare them and return:

- **0** if elements are equal
- **1** if the first element is greater than the second element
- **-1** if the first element is smaller than the second element

In your case the following callback should work:

```
$master = $master->sort(function ($a, $b) use ($order) {
  // get order of first element's section
  $pos_a = array_search($a->section, $order); 
  // get order of second element's section
  $pos_b = array_search($b->section, $order) 
  // if sections are different the value of carry doesn't matter 
  // as element's sections are enough to determine which of them is larger
  if ($pos_a != $pos_b) {
    return $pos_a - $pos_b;
  }

  // carry values are equal, so consider elements equal
  if ($a->carry == $b->carry) {
    return 0;
  }

  if (!$a->carry) {
    // if $a->carry is equal to 0 it should be put at the end, so after $b
    return 1;
  }

  if (!$b->carry) {
    // if $b->carry is equal to 0 it should be put at the end, so after $a
     return -1;
  }

  // otherwise elements can be considered equal
  return 0;
});
```

Comment: This is really close I think, thanks so much mate (this is the second time today you've come in with an amazing example, so beers are on me). However this seems to throw off completely the original order (id ASC) that the clumps were in, is there way to only sort the carry items to the bottom of each section without it swapping the order of each 'clump' - I've just realized outside of the carry items being the end of the collection everything else is in the right order.

Comment: Nevermind, I added in a return for the $a->id and $b->id and it's working perfectly. Your time and effort is VERY MUCH appreciated. thanks mate!!!

Comment: Right after the first if() statement. Cheers dude